# dotnet run fails to run in a terminal with a path outside the project

Tags: c#, .net

I have two terminals open in Visual Studio Code, one is in the path `~/Documents/learning/doka_lang_IDE/examples` and the other is in the path `~/Projects/CompilerOOPWentz/Inputer` as you can see in the image below.

[image: Image that contains two terminal open]

The problem is when I try to run the command in the terminal on the left `dotnet run --project <PATH_TO_INPUTER_PROJECT>` using the correct paths up to the path in the image on the right. When I run it, it gives a build error in the project.

However, when I run the same command in the terminal on the right, which is inside the `Inputer` path where there is a `csproj`, it builds correctly and the run executes the code correctly. You can see this in the image below.

[image: Image that contains the error and the code running]

What could be?

I tried running the dotnet command with different arguments

I tried using different paths with `~` and `/Users/`